# force:createrecord event is not working in stand alone app

Tags: lightning-aura-components

force:createrecord event is not working in stand alone app despite registering the event.Please provide inputs on it

Component 1

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

    <!-- 
    /**
     * Webkul Software.
     *
     * @category  Webkul
     * @package   Webkul_Knockout
     * @author    Webkul
     * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2016 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
     * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
     */
     -->
 <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS +
             '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css'}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

        <aura:handler name="change" action="{!c.createRecord}" value="{!v.options}"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="ModalEvent" type="c.ModalEvent"/>

    <div class="wk_static">
        <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aura:id="Modalbox" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal ">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">

                        <span>

                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </span>                 

                    <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Modal Header</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <div>
                      <ui:inputSelect class="single" aura:id="InputSelectSingle" change="{!c.selection}">
                        </ui:inputSelect>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.removecss}">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.openRecord}">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop " aura:id="MB-Back"></div>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.applycss}">Open Modal</button>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

comp 1 controller code

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        // Initialize input select options
        var opts = [
            { "class": "optionClass", label: "Select a Record Type", value: "Select"},
            { "class": "optionClass", label: "Adverse Event", value: "012n00000008hxo"},
            { "class": "optionClass", label: "Free of Charge", value: "012n00000008hxp" },
            { "class": "optionClass", label: "Lab Exam", value: "012n00000008hxq" },
            { "class": "optionClass", label: "Nurse Visit", value: "012n00000008hxr" },
            { "class": "optionClass", label: "Quality Report", value: "012n00000008hxs" },
            { "class": "optionClass", label: "Welcome Kit", value: "012n00000008hxt" }

        ];
        cmp.find("InputSelectSingle").set("v.options", opts);

    },
     applycss:function(cmp,event){
        var cmpTarget = cmp.find('Modalbox');
        var cmpBack = cmp.find('MB-Back');
        $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
        $A.util.addClass(cmpBack, 'slds-backdrop--open');
    },
    removecss:function(cmp,event){
        var cmpTarget = cmp.find('Modalbox');
        var cmpBack = cmp.find('MB-Back');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpBack,'slds-backdrop--open');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');        
    },
    selection: function(cmp,event) {
         var selectCmp = cmp.find("InputSelectSingle").get("v.value");
        console.log('selectCmp modal-->'+selectCmp);
         if(selectCmp !='Select')
         {
           //cmp.PassRecordTypeId(selectCmp);

         }



     },
      openRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
           debugger;
          var evt = $A.get("e.c:ModalEvent");
          //var evt = component.getEvent("ModalEvent");
           evt.setParams({"result":'012n00000008hxp'});
            evt.fire();

        }
})
```

Event

```
<aura:event type="Application" description="Event template">
     <aura:attribute name="result" type="String"/>

</aura:event>
```

Component 2

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:handler event="c:ModalEvent" action="{!c.openRecord2}"/>
<aura:dependency resource="force:createRecord" type="EVENT"/>

</aura:component>
```

component 2 code

```
({

      openRecord2 : function (component,event) {
          try
          {
        debugger;        
        console.log('entry inside');
        var item = event.getParam("result");
           console.log('entry1-->'+item);
       var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
       createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Service_Request__c"

        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
          }
          catch(err)
          {
              console.log(err);
          }

      }
})
```

In component 2 code create record event is not working.

Comment: A bit of code would be welcome so that we can help. Maybe it's a typo in the function call or something. Don't hesitate to post the component, controller, helper and the event so that we can determine the source of the issue

Comment: @Simon Govaert please find the code

Answer (score 0):

`force:createRecord` This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.